# VueJS - How to get data and pass this immediately after create and send to firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to get the data and show this immediatly after send to firebase. But, I just get the know data after render or reload the page again. I wanna display/show the data after send it, without have to reload the page. I tried to make get requests with mounted and created lifecycle hooks, but again, only show if the component is re-rendered or reloaded.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Http</h1>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" v-model="user.username">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" v-model="user.email">
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-success" @click="sendData">Send data</button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <ul v-for="u in users">
                    <li>{{u.username}}</li>
                    <li>{{u.email}}</li>
                    <hr>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                user:{
                    username:'',
                    email:''
                },
                users:[]
            }
        },
        methods:{
            sendData(){
                this.$http.post('FIREBASE-LINK/data.json', this.user).then(response=>{
                    console.log(response)
                }).catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err)
                })
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.$http.get('FIREBASE-LINK/data.json').then(resp=>{
                this.users = resp.body
            }).catch(err=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mounted`, as the name suggests, is only called during component creation (the Vue.js API docs say "Called after the instance has just been mounted where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el"). Since you wish to display the data after sending it to database, then your function call should be executed right after your firebase code is done.

```
methods:{
    sendData(){
        this.$http.post('FIREBASE-LINK/data.json', this.user).then(response=>{
            console.log(response)
            this.getData()
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    },
    getData: function () {
        this.$http.get('FIREBASE-LINK/data.json').then(resp=>{
            this.users = resp.body
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before, but didn't gotta nothing because I wasn't using "this.getData()", I was trying something like "getData()" only. Why in this case we should use "this"?

Comment: You use `this` because getData is exposed by Vue under the Component's object. Like the values returned by `data`, you are able to access them via `this`.